# custom input file in bootstrap 4 not show button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

When I use Custom input file in bootstrap 4, don't change my input and don't show `browse` button.

[file-browser](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser)

```
<label class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="Image" class="custom-file-input">
    <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
</label>
```

**.custom-file**

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
height: 2.5rem;
cursor: pointer;
```

**.custom-file-input**

```
min-width: 14rem;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
```

**.custom-file-control**

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 5;
height: 2.5rem;
padding: .5rem 1rem;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #555;
user-select: none;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: .25rem;
```

[image]

Comment: According to Bootstrap it is totally based on CSS. There could be some problem with your css file integration. Did you check it thoroughly?

Comment: @masud_moni Yes, I Chack All css commands and file.

Comment: Did you use any scripting code for this element?

Comment: @masud_moni No, this element doesn't need the script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as i've checked - you need to insert the  :before and :after pseudoelements - then it works.

```
.custom-file-control:before{
  content: "Browse";
}
.custom-file-control:after{
  content: "Add files..";
}
```

http://codepen.io/powaznypowazny/pen/jBqzgR

Comment: This is not the correct way as per the doc's. Please see my answer for more information. While this may get it working, it is bypassing some functionality built in to Bootstrap.

Comment: You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47971796/7120290) below to solve the __issue with non english pages and with filename capture__

Answer (score 12):

The documentation states that you should set the language of the document. For example, setting just:

```
<html lang="en">
```

was enough to get it working, unless like in @masud_moni answer, you have specified another language then use that instead of "en".

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, not the correct answer for non english pages... I prefer rafa226 answer below

Comment: This still doesn't seem to do the trick for me using version `4.0.0-beta.2`

Comment: Instead of "en" what if you were to use your own countries value? Does that not work? While my answer may not be "correct" for non-english pages, I do advise that you should use your own countries value instead of en.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code. Hope it is gonna fix your problem. It is given just under the code example in the Bootstrap page.

```
$custom-file-text: (
    placeholder: (
    en: "Choose file...",
    es: "Seleccionar archivo..."
    ),
    button-label: (
        en: "Browse",
        es: "Navegar"
    )
);
```

Comment: @JavierFuentes Please check the bootstrap documentation. You will find it there. I found it when I looked on that document

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the button, you can specify the language in your .css file and it will appear :

```
.custom-file-control:lang(fr)::before{
    content:"PARCOURIR";
}
.custom-file-control:lang(en)::before{
    content:"BROWSE";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**To show custom-file-control's placeholder and its button caption** in **non english pages** you must add to your CSS `.custom-file-control:before` and `.custom-file-control:empty::after` as in this snippet.

At this moment, there [open issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23994) to get the filename inside the custom control after selection... you can apply the `onchange` event workaround showed here.

```css
/* Valid for any language */
.custom-file-control:before {
 content: "Search";
}
.custom-file-control:empty::after {
 content: "Choose a file...";
}

/* Specific for spanish language */
.custom-file-control:lang(es)::before {
 content : "Buscar";
}
.custom-file-control:lang(es):empty::after {
 content : "Seleccionar un fichero...";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-es">
<head>
 <title>Test custom-file-control</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="mt-5 ml-5">
   <label class="custom-file">
     <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input" onchange="$(this).next().after().text($(this).val().split('\\').slice(-1)[0])" required>
     <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
   </label>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem, came here for solution, did not find it, so I continued to dig for it: the right way to do it is to have a div of class custom-file and the input and label inside it, not the input inside the label.

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="Image" class="custom-file-input">    
    <label class="custom-file" for="Image">Select file to upload</label>
</div>
```